# Why Did Bartimeus Crouch Senior free Winky?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

Was it the smart thing to do, considering she could've been hired/enslaved by other wizards and reveal his secret(s), especially the one about his death eater son?

We know Winky did end up in Hogwarts and while drunk, gave some information to Harry. 
Had her previous owner not thought about such a scenario?

Sirius, for example didn't free his slave as he wanted to keep the Order's secrets.

Comment: Well, she wasn't keeping the secret that well to begin with, considering Jr got loose (Barty's fault, but still) and she couldn't stop him.  And Barty needed a scapegoat to explain the situation.  Shortsighted, but this is a man who's trying to keep his son mind-controlled under house arrest, it's in the same territory.

Comment: Wow,  a downvote... I must've offended someone.

Comment: @Morrigan If you look at the end of GOF you'd see clearly that she would not at all reveal those secrets. Not a chance. She would have considered it even further dishonour (and she did say something to the effect that Dobby let his freedom get to his head, that they aren't supposed to have fun etc.). And as for Kreacher that's very different: you had an elf living on his own for years in a house with dark artefacts (unbeknownst to them also affected by the locket and unable to reveal Regulus's secrets) . And Sirius was nasty to him. And indeed it led to Sirius's death didn't it?

Answer (score 4):

> ‘When Winky was discovered, my father knew I must be
>   nearby. He searched the bushes where she had been found, and
>   felt me lying there. He waited until the other Ministry members
>   had left the forest. He put me back under the Imperius curse,
>   and took me home. He dismissed Winky. She had failed him.
>   She had let me acquire a wand. She had almost let me escape.’
>   Winky let out a wail of despair.

According to Crouch Jr. its because Winky failed in her task, unbeknownst to the rest of the people who witnessed the firing.

Wizards did not think of elves as a liability as we see with Sirius, he vaguely thought it a bad idea to free Kretcher(most likely Dumbledores idea to keep Kretcher), but he still wasn't careful and didn't forbid him from seeing Bellatrix and Narcissia.

Comment: Most wizards perhaps felt that way; indeed most felt they were an asset. But certainly some did (not even referring to Hermione's activism) see them not only as a liability but more importantly as a Kreacher deserving of compassion, sympathy and everything every living being deserves. Look at Regulus for example. Or indeed Dumbledore. Or indeed how Harry turns around with Kreacher. But by far unfortunately you're right. But I beg to differ that it was that Sirius didn't forbid him from seeing Bella and Cissy; more like ambiguity and Sirius's nasty tendencies towards Kreacher results in spite.